# How to get the font size and zoom used in teams settings by user in teams tab application

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

Is there any way to get the font size or zoom set by the user in teams tab application to update the font and zoom of the tab application.

Does teams provide or is there any way to get the user settings for font to use in teams tab application.

Checked some functions and tested for settings not getting any way to get the settings in teams.

Comment: The tab context provided does not contain information on how to get the font size or zoom set by the user in a Teams tab application. We can only get this info from Tab context - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context?tabs=Json-v2%2Cteamsjs-v2%2Cdefault#get-context-by-using-the-microsoft-teams-javascript-library